# How to display a user defined view on top of the camera view in android?

Tags: android, camera

I am trying to build an android app which utilizes the camera, but only shows the view of the camera on certain occasions (defined by doing some image processing on the frames given by the camera). I have been able to perform the image processing using SurfaceHandler.CallBack. For the rest of the time, I want another user defined view which displays text boxes and buttons etc. and though the camera is still on and functional, its image is obscured by my user defined view. How do I do this? I cannot use multiple activities for camera and user defined view as I have to release the camera as soon as the activity is paused. Is there a way to have multiple full-screen windows/views on top of the camera image in a single activity?

Comment: Post your layout file. You can use the FrameLayout in which both Camera view (SurfaceHolder) and user defined view is present.

Comment: @Karan Not using the layout file, only code from [here](http://ee368.stanford.edu/Android/ViewfinderEE368/ViewfinderEE368.java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code to add your views :

```
FrameLayout mContentView = new FrameLayout( LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT );
mDrawOnTop = new DrawOnTop(this);
mPreview = new Preview(this, mDrawOnTop);
mContentView.addView( mPreview, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT) );
mContentView.addView( mDrawOnTop, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT) );
setContentView( mContentView );
```

Change the height and width as per your needs.

Hope this helps.

Comment: it adds the mDrawonTop view and does the same thing as the earlier code. This method will definitely help me to add views; however, the problem is how do I set my layouts as view objects so that I can add them? In setContentView, I can directly pass my layout id, but this is not allowed for addView.

Comment: Its not similar to earlier code. The FrameLayout allows you to add views with left and top as 0. Where as setContentView adds this to ViewGroup, and addContentView will add new view to ViewGroup and you need to handle the overlapping related stuff.